# ORM Entities vs DDD Entities

Tags: java, spring, jpa, orm, domain-driven-design

I'm familiar with typical layered architecture consisting of services, entities and repositories. Services manipulate annotated entity classes which are being persisted by repositories. In this model entity classes are just anemic data containers with bunch of getters and setters. The business logic resides in the procedural service classes (singletons managed by the spring container).

I'm learning DDD as a hobby project. In DDD entities forms a rich domain model which accommodates majority of the business logic at the aggregate root methods (and value objects). Services are almost mere coordinators of collaborating entities, repositories and other services. Rich domain model enforces business constraints and invariants the true OOP way and promotes the code maintainability. Also, the domain model is the core of the *hexagonal architecture*, meaning it's just POJOs not depending on technical or framework concerns at the source code level.

But JPA specification mandates the entity bean should have public getters and setters, inherently being an anemic data container, antithesis to the DDD domain model. So should I bundle domain logic inside the JPA entity? Or should I maintain two distinct models and the mapping logic when working with ORM on DDD? Where should these model and the mapping logic live at the project level?

Comment: Really nice questions, I am starting to look DDD and when I saw the domain... I figurated in how work this in Entity model ORM's

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To maintain DDD and especially decouple your domain model from the database layer (as both may change individually), you need two distinct models.

Then, you need some kind of repository service, which knows (i.e. depends on) your domain model, and can do some kind of two-way mapping. In practice, even if this is against the pure DDD lore, you probably need some kind of assistence in your domain model (i.e. make a dump of internal structures known and restore the state from such a dump.) But it is really hard to store and restore a *real* black box in a persistent store unless you want to go for simple object serialization.

---

Regarding your question in the comment:

That's exactly the problem: you either mix your infrastructure into the domain or expose internal data. Somehow *every* author writing about DDD simply dodged this bullet by just not talking about this problem. Both variants are equally ugly, but as you seem to attempt a rather pure DDD approach, I'd create a DTO object coupled to the domain object, which is accessible by the infrastructure layer (e.g. by using package protected access). However, I would *not* grant access to the real internal values. This way you limit your "corruption" to a single point and you are free to change the implementation details as you like.

Putting some pseudo code to the answer:

```
public class Invoice {   // Domain class
    // implementation details. @Rest of the world: none of your business!
    private Person creditor;        // other domain objects
    private MonetaryAmount amount;  // and value objects

    // Corruption starts here
    toInvoiceDto() {
        InvoiceDto res = new InvoiceDto();
        res.setCreditorId(creditor.getId()); // mapping into external representation
        ...
        return res;
    }

    static Invoice fromInvoiceDto(InvoiceDto persistentSource) {
        ...
    }
    // Corruption ends here

    // do real business :^)
}

public class InvoiceDto {
    ...
}

public class Repository {
    public void saveInvoice(Invoice businessObject) {
       // *very* roughly
       InvoiceDto dto = businessObject.toInvoiceDto();
       InvoiceEntity entity = someKindOfMapper.toEntity(dto);
       entityManager.save(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Spring Data JPA. So would it be viable to include `toEntity` method into domain model classes? That would add some coupling to infrastructure however. Or maybe use package protected fields, and access these fields in the external entity builder class with same package name on the infrastructure layer?

Comment: @TuomasToivonen My answer is too long for a comment, see edit.

Comment: @mtj, about your example, why corrupt the domain model class? You could have an `InvoiceMapper` class that is part of the infrastructure, and that can convert the domain model to/from dto. This way it is the infrastructure that depends on the domain model and not viceversa.

Comment: @damsen The problem is, that the external interface of a domain entity not necessarily exposes enough information to restore its state. Therefore, you either corrupt the domain with a mapping to/from an external representation, or you give another class, which does *not* belong to the domain access to the internal structure (like with the mapper you mentioned.) Both approaches are ugly.

Comment: @mtj I see your point, thanks for the clarification! :)

Comment: why did you put the corruption inside the domain layer ? Imo the corruption should happen in the data layer

Comment: @Ced As already stated, if you keep the domain "clean", the data layer needs access to the inner structure of the domain objects. I think that's even worse, but it may suit your project better. There's no one-size-fits-all-solution here.

Comment: My view is: you design a domain with business logic because you have a set of requirements. If you did not have requirements then there is no point in making an app.

Once you have your requirements (domain) , you can implement the technical details required by your domain (data_access). High level modules (domain) should not depend on low level technicalities (data_access). 

In other words, client or yourself has requirements for the app, that's the domain layer. Then the domain layer has requirements for data_layer.

Comment: @Ced And then, later on, have the additional requirement to persist your domain entity in a database. That's what it's all about here. If you leave your domain entity "as is", the persistence layer will usually *not* have enough information to store a persistent representation of the domain object. Either you grant access to the internal structures, which is bad, or you change the domain which is also bad. Make your choice, you are between a rock and a hard place here. No choice is inherently "better" than the other, and your concrete project dictates which choice you make.

Comment: Persistence requirement was implied from the beginning, I'm not sure why you bring it like it something new. 

Look your example again, you put the dto code in the domain layer, but you have every information needed to do that operation in your data layer. High level domain does not depend on low level DAO. Inversion of control (interfaces) is used to not have the dependency from high to low. You might still have some corruption eventually, but this example is a bad one where it should not happen.

Comment: Anyway it all boils down to your statement that "if you keep the domain "clean", the data layer needs access to the inner structure of the domain objects. I think that's even worse, but it may suit your project better.", which I don't agree with (I think it's better) from a theoritical point of view, but to each his own.

Answer (score 0):

About your quote:

> But JPA specification mandates the entity bean should have public
> getters and setters, inherently being an anemic data container,
> antithesis to the DDD domain model.

I'm not an export on this topic, but as far as I know, JPA doesn't mandate public getters and setters, although documentation can be vague sometimes.

For example, the [Hibernate 5.6](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-pojo-accessors) doc says:

> 2.5.4. Declare getters and setters for persistent attributes
>
> The JPA specification **requires** this, **otherwise**, the model would prevent
> accessing the entity persistent state fields directly from outside the
> entity itself.

With "*requirement quoted above*", they probably mean this:

> The persistent state of an entity is represented by instance
> variables, which may correspond to JavaBean-style properties. An
> instance variable must be directly accessed only from within the
> methods of the entity by the entity instance itself. **The state of the
> entity is available to clients only through the entity’s accessor
> methods (getter/setter methods)** or other business methods.

These texts aren't very clear whether setters and setters are always required, even though the word "*requires*" is used. What I think what it basically says (or should say) is that if your clients wants to read and write to an attribute then you should use public getters and setters respectively. (With "*your client classes*", I mean a class that you have written, as opposed to Hibernate itself as a client of the entity.) But if your clients don't need to read or write to it, then you don't need accessor methods at all, as long as you use JPA field-access attribute annotations (as opposed to JPA method/property-access attribute annotations). Instead of setters, you could also use constructor parameters for non-null attributes. (I have plenty of such cases in my Hibernate code.) Although the JPA/Hibernate doc may have been written originally with a more anemic entity classes in mind, but you aren't required to have such anemic accessors.

About your quote:

> So should I bundle domain logic
> inside the JPA entity? Or should I maintain two distinct models and
> the mapping logic when working with ORM on DDD? Where should these
> model and the mapping logic live at the project level?

Making two distinct models would create a lot of boiler plate code.

The [JPA spec](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.0.html#persistent-fields-and-properties) says:

> In addition to returning and setting the persistent state of the
> instance, property accessor methods **may contain other business logic
> as well, for example, to perform validation**. The persistence provider
> runtime executes this logic when property-based access is used.

So having business logic in entity classes, should not be a problem.
In the ideal situation, entity classes are pure DDD domain classes, in which the ORM applied to it, is only limited to meta data (for example annotations), and the code it self is ORM agnostic.

But having a lot of ORM meta data mixed with a lot of business logic, can hurt readability. A solution to this could be extension methods in Kotlin (a Java based language). A Kotlin extension method is basically a static method in Java, that can be used as an instance method in Kotlin, that lives externally from the class to which it is logically added to.

For example, you could have the following entity class: `com.stackoverflow.domain.Question`.

And for whatever reason, you would like to add a `persist()` method to it, but you don't want to have it in the `Question` class because of separation of concerns, than you could accomplish this with extension method:

In the file `com.stackoverflow.persistence.QuestionExt.kt`:

```
package com.stackoverflow.persistence
import com.stackoverflow.domain.Question

fun Question.persist() {
    // read "id" property of question object
    val id = this.id
    // persist the question
}
```

Then client code can do this:

```
package com.stackoverflow.persistence.repositories

class QuestionRepository {
    fun save(question: Question) {
        question.persist()
    }
}
```